# Create TABLE in PHP using

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, collate

tables in my database where are some unusual letters from czech alphabet like ěščřžýáíé ignore my query. I think it could be solve via CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci, but it looks like i dont know how to use it. Iam trying this code, but for sure, there is some problem:

```
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$userreg."` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        title VARCHAR(30), 
        rating_estimate INT)")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

I have to create table in PHP code, because it depends on another variables. Browser shows "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), title VARCHAR(30), ' at line 2".

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Since it appears you are creating a new MySQL database, I suggest using MySQLi or PDO for new code (and old code for that matter....)  The mysqli_* library of functions has been deprecated.  More information can be found in the PHP manual on ["Choosing an API"](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci
```

needs to be at the end of the `CREATE` statement after the closing ')'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_set_charset()`

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');//or utf8_czech_ci
```

Or:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
```

You can also `ALTER` your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

However, it is suggested to see **[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**